# Scrape data when URL changes when the page is updated

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using requests and Beautiful Soup to parse an HTML table. However, the URL updates every time the table is updated, and if I have the code set to that URL, it will only parse the old data. How can I have requests redirect to the correct URL, or pull the identifier that updates?

For example, these two links lead to the same page.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BHF8PPB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BHF8PPB)
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BBFX5G2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BBFX5G2)

To call the URL, I have the code looping through an excel sheet containing URLs and set each URL to the variable "url".

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide some code?

Comment: I dont understand want you want to achieve, but the url ending in `B07BBFX5G2` redirects to this https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07BHF8PPB, which is almost the same as the first

Comment: The URL redirects, but when scraping the page, the page contents still hold the old table so the incorrect data is pulled.